# hbase table data export from local to production hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm planning to eport data from local hbase to my production hbase table, here i want to append exported data in to production. How can i achieve?  Can i use hbase export shell command and import in production?  does it append data to existing table? 
Are there any tools which does the same?

```
$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]

$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import <tablename> <inputdir>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [copyTable](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#copytable)

> CopyTable is a utility that can copy part or of all of a table, either to the same cluster or another cluster.

Comment: Forgot to mention that cluster ports are not visible , everything is blocked, i can not access hbase ports . Btw i need to append data into a existing table.

Comment: export and import seems to be working to append rows to existing table, it would be better if there is any sort of tool to do the same

Comment: if indeed you can't connect directly you'd indeed need to export and import :)